# Ubuntu 10.04 cronjob with curl dosen't work

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I would like to execute some php script via cron job i have curl, crontab installed, but the cron job dosen't run/create any log file.

crontab -l

```
* * * * * curl  http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?r=myController/myFuncction >> /var/www/cronJobLogs/myCtrLog.txt 2>&1
```

I executed manually this line on terminal, and the log file was created

```
curl  http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?r=myController/myFuncction >> /var/www/cronJobLogs/myCtrLog.txt 2>&1
```

UPDATE

Theroetilaclly my crons should be run in every minute.

```
root@vs3946:/var/www/cronJobLogs# whereis curl

    curl: /usr/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
    root@vs3946:/var/www/cronJobLogs# crontab -l
    # m h  dom mon dow   command
    * * * * * /usr/bin/curl  http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?r=myController/myFuncction >> /var/www/cronJobLogs/myCtrLog.txt 2>&1
    */1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl  http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?r=myController/myFuncction >> /var/www/cronJobLogs/myCtrLog.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: what's in `/var/log/cron.log`?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the full path to `curl` in your crontab - your shell knows where to find it because there's a `$PATH` environment variable available, but there's no such beast in the cron environment.

Comment: i set the path of curl but it  dosen't resolve my problem the log not exist in cronJobLog folder.